# time out when using reactor (salt)

Tags: saltstack

I have some troubles with setting up reactor in salt.
Here is my configuration:

```
reactor:
  - 'salt/minion/*/start':
    - /srv/reactor/start.sls
```

and my `/src/reactor/start.tls`:

```
{% set minion_id = data['id'] %}
highstate-for-{{ minion_id }}:
  local.state.apply:
    - tgt: {{ minion_id }}
```

I have a `master` and a `minion` that are different computers (both run 3006.3, Alma 9 for the master, Fedora 38 for the minion). When my minion fires a `start` event, it seems to correctly start the reactor but fails with a `Salt request timed out`. I tried to disable firewall with no success.

The command `salt 'minion-name' state.apply` works in 0.1s... I have no idea why it is not working...
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled using bootstrap, did not configure anything on the master and now it is working. When looking at `/etc/salt/master` and everything is set to default (nothing is uncommented). Meaning that interface is `0.0.0.0`.
I had set up the interface to be my ip address and it was apparently the problem.